# Save data in session laravel using loop

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.4

I've created a multi-step form with different views i.e `step1.blade.php, step2.blade.php,step3.blade.php`and I'm trying to save filled up data from form in session and submit it in the final step.
The current code snippet is from the step1 form:

```
    public function postBook(Request $request)
 {
     // dd($request->all());
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title.*' => 'required',
        'f_name.*'   =>'required',
        'l_name.*'   =>'required',
        'dob_month.*'   =>'required',
        'dob_date.*'   =>'required',
        'dob_year.*'   =>'required',
        'gender.*'   =>'required',
        'email.*'   =>'required',
        'contact.*'   =>'required',
        'address1.*'   =>'required',
        'address2.*'   =>'required',
        'town.*'   =>'required',
        'state.*'   =>'required',
        'mailbox.*'   =>'required',
    ]);  

    for ($i=1; $i <=limit ; $i++) { 
              Session::set('title'$i, $request->title[$i]);
              Session::set('f_name'$i, $request->f_name[$i]);
              Session::set('l_name'$i, $request->l_name[$i]);
              Session::set('dob_month'$i, $request->dob_month[$i]);
              Session::set('dob_date'$i, $request->dob_date[$i]);
              Session::set('dob_year'$i, $request->dob_year[$i]);
              Session::set('gender'$i, $request->gender[$i]);
              Session::set('email'$i, $request->email[$i]);
              Session::set('contact'$i, $request->contact[$i]);
              Session::set('address1'$i, $request->address1[$i]);
              Session::set('address2'$i, $request->address2[$i]);
              Session::set('town'$i, $request->town[$i]);
              Session::set('state'$i, $request->state[$i]);
              Session::set('mailbox'$i, $request->mailbox[$i]);
           }    
           dd($request->session()->all()); 
           return view('step2.blade.php');
}
```

The above code is returning error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$i' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')'`. If I write the line:

`Session::set('title'$i, $request->title[$i]);`

as

`Session::set('title$i', $request->title[$i]);`

It won't go with the loop. Is it possible to save data in session with loop ? How can I save these data in session with loop ?

Comment: Concatenate the $i var `Session::set('title'.$i, $request->title[$i]);` and so on.

Comment: For more detailed information of how strings in PHP work, checkout the manual about strings: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php - Take especially notice on the double-quoted strings as they allow variable interpolation.

Comment: @Mihai Tried both ways `Session::set('title'.$i, $request->title[$i]);` and `$request->session()->put("title$i", $request->title[$i]);`. The code is returning error `Undefined offset: 1`

Comment: THis means you are looping for more than limit length